# LIMIT on parent of JOIN

Tags: sql, limit, inner-join

I wish to limit the number of rows given by the parent (articles), do you know how to do this? 
I don't want to limit the total number of rows (LIMIT x), just the ones from the 'articles' table.

```
SELECT * FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories
ON articles.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN articleInfo
ON articles.id = articleInfo.article_id
INNER JOIN articleWeights
ON articles.id = articleWeights.article_id
INNER JOIN articlePictures
ON articles.id = articlePictures.article_id
WHERE articleInfo.lang = :lang
```

I'm helpless, can't find it anywhere..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention `LIMIT`, I assume you're using `MySQL`.  You can use `LIMIT` in a `subquery`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 10) articles
    INNER JOIN categories
        ON articles.category_id = categories.id
    INNER JOIN articleInfo
        ON articles.id = articleInfo.article_id
    INNER JOIN articleWeights
        ON articles.id = articleWeights.article_id
    INNER JOIN articlePictures
        ON articles.id = articlePictures.article_id
WHERE articleInfo.lang = :lang
```